# Power BI - Apply Query from Azure DevOps server stuck

Tags: team-foundation-server, microsoft-powerbi

My Power BI version is September 2019, Azure DevOps 2019
I imported data from Azure DevOps Server into Power BI report. I used out of the box analytics view (Stories - Today and Tasks - Today). I merged the tables into the stories based on Parent work item id and tried to aggregate the time fields (Original Estimate, Remaining Work and Completed Work).
For projects with few work items it worked, for projects with thousands of work items the calculation stuck on "Waiting for ".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Complex Query definitions often don't scale well. I would try to keep the Query definitions as simple as possible, e.g. without Merge Queries and aggregations.  Calculated columns are OK - not typically a performance issue.

Similar functionality to Merge Queries can be achieved using Relationships in the Model view. Similar functionality to aggregations can be achieved using Measures or Calculated Columns (DAX).